# iOS Custom Container VC and children requiring a specific orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I've tried many ways of searching for answer to this problem, but a lot of what I see is mainly locking rotation issues with `UINavigationController`s at the root view controller.

In my project, I have a custom `UIViewController` using View Controller Containment.  I did not implement the `-(BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` or `-(BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` methods because they're default implementations both already return `YES`. `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` is implemented and returning `YES`.

The first view controller that shows supports all orientations.  This is working as intended.

The second view controller that is loaded in place of the first during a segue has conditional orientation.  The view controller is essentially a view controller that contains a `UIPageViewController` for displaying the pages of a PDF.  The conditional orientation is that of the orientation of the PDF. The method `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` returns either `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` if the PDF is in landscape or `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` if the PDF is in portait.  This method does get called.  Yet, during my segue, I call:

```
[container transitionFromViewController:source 
           toViewController:dest 
           duration:1.0 
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
           animations:^{} 
           completion:^(BOOL finished){/*relevant removal of vc's from parents*/}];
```

The method calls for my supported orientations, but it doesn't seem to apply them.  I could use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:@selector(setOrientation:) withObject:(__bridge id)(void *)[dest preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];` but this app may become a store app, so I am avoiding this.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part the UINavigationController answers should get you setup. There is one trick that I have used in the past though. In my parent VC I implement the following methods:

```
- (UIViewController *)topViewController {
    return self.childViewControllers.lastObject;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [[self topViewController] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

This will sort of work but you have to rotate to a supported orientation before it will respect the second view controller's restriction. The trick is to return NO in `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` until the `viewDidAppear:` is called. Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return _viewDidShow ? YES : NO;
}
```

Then before you call the transition method call this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```